# Cut elements from multiple groups in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-production

I have multiple groups consisting of multiple shapes that overlap each other. As I want to print the design on a shirt and want the shirtcolor to shine though I can't use fill color but only outline colors.
How can I remove lines that are overlapped by another object in the forground?
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  You could just fill it white.  In printing, white = no ink.

Comment: @BillyKerr actually have to confirm first, because some printers (specifically ones for tshirts) can and do print in white ink.

Comment: @WELZ yes, but even then you could just tell them there is to be no white ink.

Comment: @BillyKerr or use spot color for white?

Comment: Thanks, but filling in a color is unfortunately no option. The customer can choose from different colors of the shirt to print the design on. So, I don't know if it will be black, dark grey or even yellow.

Comment: This might help: [Simple Spot Color Separations for Screen Printing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/18490/8708)

Comment: @phenomenia - Not sure you understand what I am saying. In printing, white is not a colour, generally speaking. When a printer makes separations for t-shirt printing, he can simply ignore the white (unless you specifically ask for white to be printed obviously).  Just make sure you tell your printer that you do not want a separation for white. Then you can safely use a white fill to mask a shape below. In the finished work, all white areas will be fully transparent (i.e. not printed), and the colour of the t-shirt will show through.  Ask your printer about this if you are still unsure.

Comment: The print on demand service is capable of printing white. Usually I use only white color (e.g. for text design) that is then printed on a black shirt for example. I plan to do the same here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to *expand any strokes* prior to doing this. This "bakes-in" the art and flattens it. So, this is a production step to be used to prepare the artwork for reproduction. It will make production easier/correct, but will also make any further aesthetic editing, with respect to placement or size of objects, *much* more difficult. A **2 file workflow** may be wise - retaining a file *before* these steps are taken will allow for easier editing in the future, Then merely repeat the below steps for a new production file.

---

Set the fills to be an off-color. Something foreign to the rest of the artwork.

[image]

1. Select all
2. **Pathfinder Panel** > `Merge` button
3. Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) and click one of the off-color areas to select it.
4. Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` from the menu
5. Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

[image]

Merge combines areas of similar color, regardless of their stacking order, and removes any underlying elements. So, by Merging you eliminate anything which was underneath the fills. Then remove the fills if they are not to be part of the artwork.